# How to Parse the database Connection String for IPV4 and IPV6

Tags: java, string, url, stringtokenizer

Im trying to parse the bunch of url.I tried using the URI class in java but it is not perfect for the different set of strings. And also i have to do the parsing on IPV6.The input strings is given below.

```
jdbc:postgresql:database
jdbc:postgresql://host/database
jdbc:postgresql://host:port/database
jdbc:postgresql://host:port/database?user=userName&password=pass
jdbc:postgresql://host:port/database?charSet=LATIN1&compatible=7.2

jdbc:postgresql://[::1]:5740/accounting (IPV6)
```

I want the hostname,port,and database name.

Guide me !

Comment: Can you brief your question.

Comment: The given url are inputs in terms of ipv4 and ipv6 database conn string !! I wud lik to get the hostname,port,and db name.I used URI class but i cudnt fetch the proper result!!

Answer (score 3):

```
    String cleanURI = s.substring(5);
    URI uri = URI.create(cleanURI);
    System.out.println(uri.getScheme());
    System.out.println(uri.getHost());
    System.out.println(uri.getPort());
    System.out.println(uri.getPath());
```